# MySQL changing system date doesn't have the expected results

Tags: php, mysql, date

I'm building a date specific PHP script.

This script will perform a specific task when its Sunday. I've written my PHP code and I'm trying to test it. Since it's not Sunday today, I set my system date to last Sunday. The thing is that my MySQL query doesn't return the expected results

```
SELECT date FROM schedules WHERE name='someName' AND date >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY )
```

The query above will return the records of the current date plus and minus 3 days.

Here is an example of the output I get:

```
2015-11-26
2015-11-29
2015-11-30
2015-12-04
2015-12-02
```

The result that I need is:

```
 2015-11-26
 2015-11-29
```

Another query:

```
SELECT date FROM schedules WHERE name='someName' AND date >= (CURDATE() -  3 )
```

The query above will return all the dates that are 3 days older than the current date not including the last 3 days of the current date.

I only want it to return the last 3 days of the current date.

Comment: Won't changing to `>=` (greater than or equal) do the trick? Or maybe just "greater than", if you don't want the current date.

Comment: I changed my code. I had it as you suggested and it was then that I got the results that I decribed. Still it will return -+ 3 days and not just - 3 days of my curdate().

Comment: I'm confused. Can you add some sample output that illustrates the problem please

Comment: Yes here you are. I've set my system date to 11/29 which is last Sunday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm trying to understand the output you want. So you want to get dates that are no more than 3 days prior to the current date and nothing in the future.

So on '2015-12-04' the result would be:

```
2015-12-04
2015-12-03
2015-12-02
2015-12-01
```

So maybe the `BETWEEN` Clause will do the trick

```
SELECT date FROM schedules 
WHERE name='someName' 
  AND (date BETWEEN (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY ) AND CURDATE() );
```

Comment: Ok, I think my query still does the job.

Comment: Yes the between statement did the trick! Thanks a lot I will accept your answer as soon as I can.